# Can I obtained guest instruction with QEMU plugin or other means?

Tags: qemu

I want to obtained the guest instructions while QEMU emulating. Is it possible to do such a task? Why I have this problem is that i want to obtain the load/store instructions and read the reg and mem data.

I know there is a related problem from this:[Qemu plugin functions - how to access guest memory and registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821772/qemu-plugin-functions-how-to-access-guest-memory-and-registers.But)  what i really want to know now is that could i obtain the guest instructions by QEMU plugins or other means?